# File does not begin with '%pdf'

Tags: php, pdf, yii, fpdf

im using fpdf to convert a php output into a pdf file. i tried to copy out a sample code of theirs to see how it looks. but when i run my program, i get this error:

```
File does not begin with '%PDF-'.
Local\EWH-4080-27
```

i googled some solutions but none worked. something i also noticed was that the last number(27) was increasing by 2 every time i ran my program and encounter the error. the sample code i copied is this:

```
<?php
require('protected/extensions/fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

im also working on yii. im wondering of this problem has something to do with my code or my adobe reader or something.

Comment: Well, does the actual file begin with %PDF- or not?

Comment: Where do you see that error appear? Did you try searching StackOverflow? There are several questions already posted with this exact same title. Maybe one of those posts are applicable to you.